# Linear Regression evaluation using $R^2$

Tags: regression, r-squared, model-evaluation

Sum of squared error can be used to evaluate the model and compare them to see which one is lower, however this evaluation metric is sensitive to number of observations used.

Coming to $R^2$, this is robust evaluation metric as it is not sensitive to number of observations. The question I have here is, sum of squared can be calculated on train or test data. What about $R^2$, should I use train data or test data or both? How should I interpret if $R^2$ is lower/higher compared between train and test data?

Comment: Assuming you mean $R^2$, a substantially lower $R^2$ statistic on the test data than on the training data is a sign of possibly having overfitted the model

Comment: $R^2$ works poorly for test data as it does not reflect bias, only variance. So $R^2$ might be the same for a model producing high bias and another producing low bias. Therefore, use mean squared error instead.

Comment: @RichardHardy thx, but in which cases we need to check R2 on train data vs. test data?

Comment: I would never use $R^2$ on test data.

Comment: @RichardHardy if I understand R^2 correctly it is explained variance. So, on test data the variance may more more so R^2 becomes low, till this I understand. But when you say low bias (it is error or, difference b/w actual vs. predicted), I'm thinking it will imply lower variance. So, higher bias >> higher variance &  lower bias >> lower variance. what am I missing? thx

Comment: No, high bias $\not\rightarrow$ high variance and low bias $\not\rightarrow$ low variance. Also, bias is not the same as forecast error (difference between actual vs. predicted). Bias is the expectation of forecast error.

Comment: @RichardHardy so is there a way to calculate bias then? or is it just unpredictable as we don't know the population

Comment: For training data, just use (root) mean squared error, mean absolute error, mean absolute percentage error, mean absolute scaled error, or the like. They account for both bias and variance at once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52426/discussion-between-yome-and-richard-hardy).